# How to merge a part of changes from other git repositories

Tags: git

I have a git repository with Android kernel v3.0.36.
But now, Linux 3.0.38 is out. Android and mainline Linux are incompatible, so I just want to pull the changes from 3.0.37 and 3.0.38 (just a small part of changes). And I don't want to pull other changes.

I'm using Github. I saw many people's logs are like that:

net: wireless:bcm4329: Fix Unknown escape '%'
90fcf01d79 Browse code 
Choi, Jong-Hwan authored 8 months ago
 xxx committed 3 months ago

How can they do it? And how can I do it?

Comment: There are ~90 changes between .36 and .38. It will be a bit hard to cherry-pick some without making a mess of dependencies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in "[Create a single patch between two tags with multiple commits between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078820/create-a-single-patch-between-two-tags-with-multiple-commits-between-them)", you could create a single path between v3.0.36. and 3.0.38, specifying the subdirectory which is of interest to you within one repo.

```
git diff tag1 tag2 -- /path/to/subdir > the-patch.diff
```

The idea is, you can apply a diff to another repo.

Regarding GitHub, the same mechanism apply with [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/): once you have patched locally, you can push to our GitHub repo which should be a **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo)**, and then make a pull request.

---

As [fork0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410126/fork0) comments, `git diff` would loose the comments associated with the commit.
`git format-patch` is a better solution (and I upvoted fork's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615326/6309)).
I would consider `cherry-pick` only if you are aware of [its limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881112/6309).

---

As [commit like this one](https://github.com/biergaizi/AIR-Kernel_ICS/commit/27aec2107c6c9f0aea46ebc011ee17357ee8e784) is the result of a pull request done by gregkh, accepted by edoko.

Comment: I'm using Github. I saw many people can do it easily.

I need to see logs on Github like that:

net: wireless:bcm4329: Fix Unknown escape '%' 
Choi, Jong-Hwan authored 8 months ago
someone committed 3 months ago

Comment: @比尔盖子 : I have edited my answer. could you also provide a link to one of those commits you see on GitHub?

Comment: Don't use `git diff` for this, you'll loose commit descriptions, which are as valuable as the changes themselves

Comment: @VonC OK, see this commit:
https://github.com/biergaizi/AIR-Kernel_ICS/commit/27aec2107c6c9f0aea46ebc011ee17357ee8e784

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the other branch in your repository and cherry-pick the commits you need. See `git cherry-pick`, or alternatively `git show --pretty=email <commit-id> |git am -3`, or even `git format-patch -o /tmp v3.0.37..v3.0.38`, followed by `git am -3 /tmp/<file>` for the interesting, and possibly edited, patches

Comment: OK, this is the things I want. But, I just want to pull the changes from 3.0.37 and 3.0.38 (just a small part of changes). And I don't want to pull other changes. If I pull mainline Linux into a branch of my repository, then I have to merge everything!

Comment: Don't do this, than. The format-patch command in given in the example extracts just the patchs from .37 to .38